# Leer una linea ingresada y compararla caracter por caracter con otro caracter previamente ingresado

Tags: array, c, caracteres

Ejemplo de salida en pantalla:

> ```
> Ingrese la letra a buscar
>
> c
>
> Ingrese la frase:
>
> como cocinas
>
> +omo +o+inas
> ```

No es necesario guardar nada ni leer todo primero y luego imprimir, por lo tanto se me indicó que no es necesario hacerlo con arreglos o string.

Lo que no entiendo es cómo leo caracter por caracter la frase ingresada sin usar arreglos. esto es lo que hice hasta ahora.

```
int main()
{
    char letra;
    char oracion;


    printf("Ingrese el caracter a buscar:\n");
    letra=getchar();
    getchar();

    printf("Ingrese la oracion:\n");
    oracion=getchar();
    getchar();


    while(oracion!='.'){
        if(oracion==letra){
            oracion='+';
            printf("%c", oracion);
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿cuál es el problema con tu código?

Comment: A la oración la tengo que comparar caracter por caracter con la letra ingresaday no se como hacerlo sin arreglos...o tal vez sea usando un for. Ese código ni siquiera funciona, da error. Lo puse como para mostar en qué estoy.

Answer (score 1):

> No es necesario guardar nada ni leer todo primero y luego imprimir

Te engañaron. Leer todo, procesarlo e imprimirlo es la manera adecuada de hacerlo. Las restricciones que te ponen son absurdas e incoherentes.

---

Por suerte, pese a lo absurda de la petición es fácil de programar. La entrada de datos en C funciona mediante [búferes](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%BAfer_de_datos). Puedes extraer datos del búfer de entrada con diferentes funciones entre ellas: la que ya estás usando [`getchar`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar).

La función `getchar` extrae un carácter del búfer de entrada (el secuencia [FIFO](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_in,_first_out#Inform%C3%A1tica)), de no haber nada que extraer devuelve [EOF](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/EOF), por lo tanto podemos leer de la entrada y escribir en la salida sin guardar nada y sin usar arreglos de la siguiente manera:

```
int main(void)
{
    char c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        printf("%c", c);

    return 0;
}
```

Por lo tanto, para reemplazar una letra por la que se entró, se puede hacer en el mismo bucle:

```
int main(void)
{
    printf("Introduce una letra");
    char letra;
    scanf("%c", &letra);

    printf("Introduce una frase");
    char c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        printf("%c", c == letra ? '+' : c);

    return 0;
}
```